Proving $f^{-1}(f(U)) \subset U\ker f$.
Let $f: G \to H$ be a homomorphism between the groups $G$ and $H$. Define $U$ as a subgroup of $G$.
I have to prove that $f^{-1}(f(U)) \subset U\ker f$.
This is what I found:
Take an element $x$ from $U \ker f \implies f(x) \in f(U \ker f)$. The only thing we know about $f$ is that it's a homomorphism so $f(x) = f(x1) = f(x)f(1) = f(x)1$ and $f(x)1 \in U\ker f$. So $f^{-1}(f(x)f(1)) \in f^{-1}f(U \ker f).$ But we don't know that f is injective so why is $f^{-1}f(U \ker f) = U \ker f$?

It's not clear what $Uker f$ is supposed to mean.

How I interpreted it was: U$\operatorname{ker} $f = ${ux : u \in U$ and $x \in \operatorname{ker f} }$

Use \operatorname{ker} to get $\operatorname{ker} f$

@VivaanDaga \ker also works

@BenGrossmann Yes, indeed, I changed it.

@VivaanDaga Thanks for the tip.

I think this is an equality: $f^{-1}(f(U)) = f^{-1} (f(U) {e}) =U f^{-1}({e}) = U \ker f$.

In general, if you have that $f(a)=f(b)$, then $ak=b$, where $k\in \ker f$. This is because $ab^{-1}$ would belong to $\ker f$. $f^{-1}(f(U)) $ is the set of all elements that map to an element of $f(U)$. So, if $x\in f^{-1}(f(U)) $, then $f(x)=f(u)$ for some $u\in U$, which implies that $x=uk$ for some $k\in \ker f$, from which what you want follows.

Suppose that $x \in f^{-1}(f(U))$. That is, $f(x) \in f(U)$. It follows that for some element $u \in U$, we have $f(x) = f(u)$. Thus, we have
$$
[f(u)]^{-1} f(x) = 1_H \\
f(u^{-1})f(x) = 1_H \\
f(u^{-1}x) = 1_H
$$
That is, $u^{-1}x \in \ker f$. Thus, we can write $x = u(u^{-1}x)$, so that $x$ can indeed be written as the product of an element of $U$ and an element of $\ker f$. That is, $x \in f^{-1}(f(U))\subset U\ker f$, which is what we wanted.
